# How to call a function on a C program by a cron job scheduler to call the function everyday in ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, cron

I've heard that we can call the .out file of a C program in a cron job but can I call a function within the program on a cron job which needs to be executed every day ??
I know to call a c program once in a 25 minutes everyday is,
25 * * * * /home/users/Desktop/abc.out

but how to call a particular function on that program every day ??
Please help me on this as I am new to cron job scheduling. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to write the program such that the function can be called by running the program with the required args.

Comment: with cron you can execute command lines at defined times. If you know how to call your function from the command line, that'll be the answer to your question (maybe apart from some details to get the execution environment set up correctly). If your C program doesn't allow you to solely execute that specific function, you'll have to develop a new program that does (or add that feature to the existing program).

Comment: @kaylum Yes but I should call the particular function on a specific time interval i.e., after 25 mins daily,. So I've opted for a cron job scheduling. I don't know to call the particular function in a scheduled manner

Comment: please provide more info namely: the function and its args, possibly where you "heard"

Comment: Those are two seperate issues. 1. Write a program that calls the function when passed specific args. 2. Run the program with those args in crontab.

Comment: Do you know how to write a C program, compile and run it? Do you know how a C program can look at the command line argument he get when run? Do you know how to use the if/then/else and switch C statements? If you do, then follow @kaylum advice above. If you don't, do some research, try to write some code and then when you are stuck, ask a new specific question about what you don't know.

Comment: @Ronald I want to run a particular function once on a 30 minutes to check the function on refresh interval. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: I'd be happy to help you. So first we'll have to find out how to execute just this specific function. If that's not possible, we'll have to create a program that does it. Either way, we'll end up with a method to call that function, and we'll then be able to automate its invocation.

Comment: Yeah @Ronald but how can we execute a specific function by a cornjob ??

Comment: Forget about the part "by a cronjob" first, because that's not the issue here. You have some program and this program contains a function. The question now is: is there a way to run that program such that just this function is executed, or not? If not, you'll have to create a program that does nothing more than just to call that special function. Either way, we know what command line will execute that function (the original program with some command line flags to indicate that only that function should be called, or your dedicated newly developed program), and we can use that to feed cron

Answer (score 0):

Cron is a service to execute a program on a scheduled basis, not a service to call a program's function.  So to call a program's function you need to write a program that calls that function.  If you read the crontab(5) man page, you will see how to call a program in a periodic basis.  A C program always calls its `main()` function first, so you can do that writing a program that calls it, but you need to use different programs with different `main()` routines, each calling the actual function you want to call.  This will load the shared object only once and you can call a small program to run the actual function without reloading all functions each time.  Another approach is to make a normal library and write each function in a different (isolated) compilation unit, when you link the linker will select only the modules you are statically linking and each program will have only the function you want executed.

If you design and build a shared lib, then you can make different small programs, with a different `main()` routine each, and they can be linked dynamically with each main callint one of the different functions you want executed, but I think this is out of scope to explain how to do this without knowing comletely what is the exact problem you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of conventional, compiled programs written in languages like C, the fundamental unit of modularity — the coin of the realm — is the *function*.  Just about anything interesting you can do will involve calling a function to do it.

In the world of Unix and Linux, on the other hand, the fundamental unit of modularity is the *program*.  Just about anything interesting you can do will involve invoking a program to do it.

These two worlds overlap, of course, but this means that there are a lot of programs which are actually just thin, command-line-callable wrappers around interesting functions.  One good example is `stat`: there's a library function (which strictly speaking is also a system call) [`stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), and then there's also a command-line-callable program [`stat(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

So yes, if you have an interesting task, that you want to get run out of `cron`, and if you currently have only a function for performing that task, you're almost certainly going to have to write a small program — a "thin wrapper" — containing, at least, a definition of `main()` containing a call to your function.  This is precisely the same thing you'd need to do if you wanted to perform that task — call that function — from the command line.

It might seem that it ought not to be necessary to write these thin wrapper programs.  It might be nice if there was some kind of general-purpose solution to the problem of calling functions from the command line.  And, in fact, at least theoretically there is.  One possibility is a *C interpreter*.  For example, with a C interpreter called `ci` I might write:

```
ci -c 'printf("%x\n", 42);'
```

This is a command-line invocation which is sufficient to invoke the interpreter, asking it to call the C function `printf` in a certain way, and without writing a special-purpose program to do it.  The only problem here is that `ci` is not a standard program; it's one I wrote myself.  (In the real world, of course, there's a `ci` command which is part of RCS, and which does something completely different.)